# How to run Ansible playbooks on Redhat Linux from Windows CLI?

Tags: cmd, ansible, command-line-interface

I have a project where I have a cluster of Linux Redhat hosts, however I want to run a playbook through my Windows Command Prompt. I have checked out the documentation on their official website, but I didn't see much about my approach. I know it may not be conventional or smart to run it from a Windows CLI but I want to see if I could do it. I tried one line of code below:

**Command:**

```java
ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a stock windows machine as a control node is [not supported](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#control-node-requirements).

There are however 2 options that will let you run ansible from windows:

- [Running from cygwin](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/running-ansible-within-windows)
- [Running from wsl](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/using-ansible-through-windows-10s-subsystem-linux) (windows 10).